# Raphael US SVG map not recoloring when values change

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

I'm writing some code using this Raphael-based map, which is an SVG jQuery plugin: http://newsignature.github.io/us-map/

I've got the map to color itself based on values (support) in an array (USA) that have been pushed into an object (statesObject).

It all works nicely, until I redefine the support values - and much as the object recognizes the values have changes, the map stays the same whatever I do.

I'd welcome any advice you can offer me. The relevant code is below.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      colorMap();
    });

    function colorMap(){
      var statesObject = {};
      for(var i = 0; i < USA.length; i++) {
        var national = (USA[i]);
        var colorState = national.id;
        if (national.support < 50) {
          statesObject[colorState] = {fill: '#cd3700'};
        } else if (national.support >= 50){
          statesObject[colorState] = {fill: '#232066'}
        }
      }
      $('#map').usmap({stateSpecificStyles: statesObject})
    }

    function nationalChange(){
      for(var i = 0; i < USA.length; i++) {
        var national = (USA[i]);
        national.support += 5;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see there is no way to update the map when you have changed something, especially from *external* input i.e. clicking a button or updating a field.

It may be a bit hacky but the quickest solution I found was to *redraw* the map by removing it and re-adding it with the new values.

```
function redrawMap() {
  $('#map').remove()

  var statesObject = {};

  for(var i = 0; i < USA.length; i++) {
    var colorState = USA[i].id
    if (USA[i].support < 50) {
      statesObject[colorState] = {fill: '#cd3700'}
    } else if (USA[i].support >= 50){
      statesObject[colorState] = {fill: '#232066'}
    }
  }

  $('#container').append('<div id="map"></div>')

  $('#map').usmap({ stateSpecificStyles: statesObject })
}
```

The key parts being `$('#map').remove()` which removes the map from the page and then `$('#container').append('<div id="map"></div>')` which adds it back to the page thus allowing to be *redrawn*.

Comment: This is amazing. I don't have the ability to rate your answer, but this absolutely worked!